# Rails variable data is changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables that has many to many association

students 
projects

connected through the table student_projects

```
student = Student.find(1)
old_projects = student.projects

#Now Iam calling function that will create projects
create_projects

student = Student.find(1)
new_projects = student.projects
newly_added_projects = new_projects - old_projects
```

Old projects were empty,new_projects weren't

I put the logger statement before creating and after line(new_projects = students.projects), then I can see the difference.

But when I put the logger statement only after line (newly_added_projects = new_projects - old_projects) inspecting old_projects, new_projects, newly_added_projects

then  old_projects is equal to new_projects

Can someone help me in this

Comment: Rails tries to defer database access until the data is actually needed. I'm not sure how Rails 3 behaves, but my guess is that `old_projects = student.projects` does not return an array, but some kind of proxy. And that both queries are executed upon invoking `-` (so both return the same result). Try to enforce the query by adding a `to_a`, i.e. `old_projects = student.projects.to_a`

Comment: What is the Rails version you are using?

Comment: Stefan -- Thanks that's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to collect the project ids before and after creating new projects and subtract the ids of old project ids and new project ids like below,

```
student = Student.find(1)
old_project_ids = student.projects.map(&:id) # You may use student.project_ids

#Now Iam calling function that will create projects
create_projects

student = Student.find(1)
new_project_ids = student.projects.map(&:id)
newly_added_project_ids = new_project_ids - old_project_ids
```

Else you may convert the **old_projects** object from active record relation to plain ruby array like below,

```
student = Student.find(1)
old_projects = student.projects.to_a

#Now Iam calling function that will create projects
create_projects

student = Student.find(1)
new_projects = student.projects_to_a
newly_added_projects = new_projects - old_projects
```

Comment: You should use `pluck(:id)` if you are just interested in the ids.

Comment: Yes, we can use pluck. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
student = Student.find(1)
old_projects = student.projects

newly_added_projects = create_projects # return newly projects from method itself.

def create_projects
  projects = []

  #add newly created projects in projects array and return at the end.
  return projects
end
```

Do something like that. No need of calculating it from old you have already projects in your create_projects method.

Comment: This has nothing to do with an issue, that as @Stefan explained in the comment is related to deferring SQL query execution.